# exposing a private type through a public function

Tags: types, go, visibility

I was testing go's type visibility and received unexpected behavior when I exposed a private type through a public function:

```
package pak

type foo struct { // shoudn't be visible to any other package than pak
    Bar string
}

func NewFoo(str string) *foo {
    return &foo{str}
}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "pak"
)

func main() {
    // these lines should be equivalent...
    var f = pak.NewFoo("Hello, World!")         // this works fine...   
    var f *pak.foo = pak.NewFoo("Hello, World!") // ERROR: cannot refer to unexported name pak.foo

    fmt.Printf("%T\n", f)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", f.Bar)  // how does it know about .Bar, if it can't see pak.foo?
}
```

Without explicitly declaring the type of `f`, it prints:

```
*pak.foo
Hello, World!
```

but with `*pak.foo` it fails to compile.

Why doesn't it fail in both cases?

(this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773192/private-type-with-exported-fields) is sort of related, but it does not answer this question)

Answer (score 3):

The valid statement

```
var f = pak.NewFoo("test")
```

gives you an anonymous, hidden address for the `struct` `foo`. You can't use it to read from or write to the `struct` `foo` outside the `pak` package. You can, and usually  will, use it to call a `pak` package method. For example,

```
p := f.PakMethod()
```

The invalid statement

```
var f *pak.foo = pak.NewFoo("test")
```

attempts to obtain the address of the `struct` `foo`. If permitted, this would allow you to read from and write to the `struct` `foo` outside the `pak` package.

Comment: I didn't know there were anonymous types. But it's valid to read/write from/to `struct foo` outside of `pak`. It's not a pure anonymous struct/interface, it exactly the same as `*pak.foo`, but you're not allowed to write it, because you can't see `pak.foo`. But you must know all about `pak.foo`, because you can call all its methods, pass it in functions in `pak` with parameters of type `pak.foo` or access the fields. That seems paradox to me. I guess exposing a private struct doesn't make much sense anyway.